# get contents of a file from user's public github repos in ruby

Tags: ruby, github

I'd like to write a little ruby script to iterate through all of the public repos for a user and get a specific file if it is there.  Here's a little code snippet that can be run in irb where the file exists, but I'm getting a 404, so there must be something wrong, but I don't see it:

```
require 'octokit'
user = Octokit.user 'octokit'
repos = user.rels[:repos].get.data

>   repos[3].name
 => "octokit.rb"

Octokit.contents repos[3], path:'Gemfile'

Octokit::NotFound: GET https://api.github.com/contents/Gemfile: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
```

That particular repo (https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) definitely has a file named 'Gemfile' at the root level, but it's still reporting a 404.

Comment: the correct path to that location is `https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/Gemfile` where the path equates to `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:file_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're looking for

```
require 'octokit'
user = Octokit.user("octokit")
repos = user.rels[:repos].get.data
Octokit.contents repos[3].full_name, path:"Gemfile"
```

`Octokit#contents` accepts the following object types for `repo`:

```
Integer @id = repo
String @owner, @name = repo.split('/') #this is what I used with #full_name
Repository @owner = repo.owner;  @name = repo.name
Hash @name = repo[:repo] ||= repo[:name]; @owner = repo[:owner] ||= repo[:user] ||= repo[:username]
```

When you use `get.data` you do not actually have a `Repository` you have a `Sawyer::Resource` which has no handling so when it generates the url you get `/`.

There might be better ways but this is the easiest way to adapt your specific code.

**Update**

make the `repos` more accessible you could create a `Hash` like this:

```
repos = Hash[user.rels[:repos].get.data.map{|r| [r.name, Octokit::Repository.new(r.full_name)]}]
#=> {"go-octokit"=>octokit/go-octokit, "octokit.net"=>octokit/octokit.net, "octokit.objc"=>octokit/octokit.objc, "octokit.rb"=>octokit/octokit.rb}
Octokit.contents repos["octokit.rb"], path: "Gemfile"
```

I think this adds a bit to readability or you could monkey patch `Sawyer::Resource`

```
class Sawyer::Resource
  def to_repo
    Octokit::Repositiory.new(self.full_name)
  end
end
repos = user.rels[:repos].get.data.map(&:to_repo) #this will return an array of `Octokit::Repository` Objects
Octokit.contents repos[3], path:'Gemfile'
```

Comment: @Ultrasaurus i updated my answer with a few other things that might be useful to you depending on your implementation.